# DD-WRT and mount command

Tags: mount, samba, busybox, dd-wrt

I want to mount my usb drives using UUID or Labels. The busybox provided mount does not support these functions.

I installed mount-utils from entware. However the busybox mount overrides the mount from mount-utils.

I have installed DD-WRT v24 sp2 kongac build:26365 on Netgear r7000.

How do I do this? I need this as I have two different usb drives which I need to mount at specific points to use samba server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this busybox comes with `findfs` you can do

```
mount $(findfs UUID=cb586ec4-e121-437c-83db-e46df501e046) /mnt/dest
mount $(findfs LABEL=foobar) /mnt/dest
```

Otherwise you'll just have to find room for a better version of busybox I guess? You can download some precompiled ones for various architectures here: http://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/latest/